# Trouble translating English to FOL with Quantifiers

Tags: translation, quantification

The sentence is: Of all the students, only Claire was angry at 3:00

Here is what I think it is: ∀x [(Student(x) ∧ Angry(x, 3:00)) → x=claire]

The textbook (LPL) uses these names and predicates for this specific sentence:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ∀x [(Student(x) ∧ Angry(x, 3:00)) → x=claire]

Close.

This merely sais, "Any student who is angry at 3:00, is Clair." This may be satisfied when *no* student is angry then.  It does *not* affirm that Clair *is* angry at 3:00, *nor* that she is a student.

You must say: "Clair is a student who is angry at 3:00, *and* any student who is angry at 3:00, is Clair."